# Azure Blob Image Upload 405 (The resource doesn't support specified Http verb)

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am attempting to upload an image (an HTML5 canvas converted to an image which is working as intended) to Azure Blob Storage using JavaScript. At this stage, I am less concerned with file size and most concerned with being able to post the file to Azure Blob Storage. I have read a lot of different articles about SAS and for the intents of testing I have a public container, but need to learn how to generate SAS. At this point, I just need to be able to post. I have configured my blob account with CORS as follows:

```
Allowed Origins: http://localhost:50045
Allowed Methods: DELETE,GET,NONE,POST,PUT
Allowed Headers: content-length,accept,x-ms-*
Exposed Headers: x-ms-*
Max Age (seconds): 10000
```

When I use the following upload code, which is working to upload to a separate vendors Web Service, I get the following error:

```
405 (The resource doesn't support specified Http Verb.)
```

Here is my code:

```
$scope.reRender = function () {
    var canvasImage = document.getElementById("c");
    var img = canvasImage.toDataURL("image/png");
    var filename = 'Test';

    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append(filename, img);

    var send = function (blob) {
        var filename = 'Test.png';
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append('File1', blob, filename);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://myblobaccount.blob.core.windows.net/blob1',
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("Upload to Azure complete!");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log("Something went wrong!");
            }
        })
    }

    var canvasImage = document.getElementById("c");
    if (!canvasImage.toBlob) {
        var dataURL = canvasImage.toDataURL();
        var bytes = atob(dataURL.split(',')[1])
        var arr = new Uint8Array(bytes.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = bytes.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        send(new Blob([arr], { type: 'image/png' }));
    }
    else
        canvasImage.toBlob(send);
}
```

Does Azure Blob Storage not support a POST? Or is my upload code not in alignment with what Azure is looking for to POST the image file into "blob1"?

Comment: I have also tried using a wildcard for allowed origins, but it didn't work as Azure Storage Explorer stated that "An Allowed Origin must be a value URI"

Answer (score 2):

Azure blob storage does not support HTML form based file upload, AWS S3 supports this. So POST is not supported by Azure Blob storage. I think it supports PUT, you can try PUT.

But doing all this in JavaScript is dangerous, anyone can put items after acquiring necessary shared signature. If you are not providing shared access signature, blob storage will not allow any operation at all.

Instead you must upload file to your server, PHP, ASP or anything and then connect to Azure via its SDK and save it. Or create a shared signature with rights.

Comment: I tried a PUT but received an error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:50045' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403". This Microsoft article has a section for uploading using JavaScript: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/02/03/windows-azure-storage-introducing-cors.aspx, but do you have any information on how I get the Shared Access Signature using JavaScript?

Comment: So for testing purposes, I have it as public with a PUT and am getting a CORS error despite CORS being enabled as above.

Answer (score 1):

You must get *SASToken* and add it to your path,

use type: `"PUT"`,

use `headers: [{ name: 'x-ms-blob-type', value: 'BlockBlob' }]`

Something like this:

```
<code> 
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FileUploader, FileItem, Headers } from 'ng2-file-upload';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class Uploader {
    public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({ url: URL, method: 'PUT' });
    public hasBaseDropZoneOver: boolean = false;
    public files: FileItem[] = this.uploader.queue;

    public r: Response;

    constructor(private httpClient: Http){}

    public getUploader(): FileUploader {
        return this.uploader;
    }

    public fileOverBase(e: any): void {
        this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
    }    

    public uploadAll(): void {

        this.httpClient.get(getToken)
            .subscribe(
            result => {
                if (result.ok) {

                    for (var n = 1; n <= this.files.length; n++) {                        

                        let fullUrl = URL + this.files[n].file.name + result.json();
                        console.log('--> send url ' + fullUrl);

                        this.uploader.setOptions({
                            url: fullUrl, method: 'PUT',
                            headers: [{ name: 'x-ms-blob-type', value: 'BlockBlob' }]
                        });

                        this.uploader.uploadItem(this.files[n]);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    console.log('--> get token error ' + result.statusText);
                }                
            });                
    }

    public cancelAll(): void {
        this.uploader.cancelAll();
    }

    public clearQueue(): void {
        this.uploader.clearQueue();
    }    
}
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below is my CORS properties setting which work to me, hope this will be helpful.

```
Allowed Origins: *
Allowed Methods: GET,PUT
Allowed Headers: *
Exposed Headers: *
Max Age (seconds): 200
```